# How to avoid bottle necks when working with many threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following loop:

```
// myList is an ArrayList (10000 elements)
for(MyObject test : myList) {
    test.calculate();
}
```

And I thought that it is a good candidate to parallelization since every `calculate()` operation does not depend on anything else, it only makes some math operations using some variables within the same object.

I know doing the following will have a negative impact on performance since I will be creating 10000 threads which will create a huge queue on my 4 cores processor:

```
// myList is an ArrayList (10000 elements)
for(MyObject test : myList) {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            test.calculate();
        }  
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

The question is, what's the recomended way to work with multiple threads on this type of scenarios to avoid queuing?

Comment: _to avoid queuing_ - you will always have a queue if you have more work then CPU time; the question becomes where is that queue? Before submission to the thread pool? Or after submission? To avoid overloading your CPU, maybe just use a fixed size thread pool equal to the number of cores in your system. You can then submit all you want, but it will only execute _n_ at once. Your currently implementation spins up hundreds of threads instantly which will definitely bog down your system.

Comment: You could try that out. I would be very much surprised if using more than say two or four times threads than numbers of available cores gives any advantage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler approach is to take advantage of Java 8 parallel streams.

```
myList.parallelStream().forEach( MyObject::calculate);
```

The JVM maintains a pool of threads for such tasks, with as many threads as there are cores (or hyperthreads) on the computer. It does not spin up a new pool every time it encounters parallel code; nor does it spin up a new thread for every iteration.

Of course, with any performance issue, do benchmarking. There is some overhead to forking work among multiple threads and then joining the results (presumably you want to capture the results). So make sure the savings outweigh the overhead.

Comment: The pool used by parallel streams is shared across JVM so if there is another thread also doing `parallelStream()` performance improvement will not be that great

Comment: That's the point. At the point that you create more threads than cores, then you're just context switching anyway. Better to let the JVM manage that.

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach would be to use [an `ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) - based on your description, you want to use one thread per processor:

```
int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

for (MyObject test: myList) {
  executor.submit(test::calculate);
}

executor.shutdown();
```

The executor maintains an internal queue which will hold the tasks until the previous ones are completed.

Comment: How are the results stored?

Comment: @Trilarion based on the code in the question I assumed that calculate doesn't return a value. If it did then you could simply place the returned futures in a list a loop over that list after having submitted the jobs.